# How to append a stream record to previous data recorded?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming, hls

I have a question about the append process in FFmpeg. Actually I have a live stream that comes from Wowza in HLS format (`.m3u8` and `.ts`). Everything works fine if the stream doesn't fails.

In this situation, when the stream restart, sometimes the FFmpeg can get the new chunks, but it overwrites the content already downloaded.

So, my question is: Is there a flag that I use in FFmpeg that enables it to append (or concat) the content of a HLS stream to the end of the previous data already recorded?

Comment: Also, how to make ffmpeg more resilient to failures?

Answer (score 2):

After reading some docs/site I've found this reference that presented an alternative to reach this: http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/hls-2.htm.gz

All I needed to do is to use those flags:

```
-hls_flags append_list
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!